# Improved titles for comments in user feeds

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

I see comments now appear in user feeds.

Currently they all are titled like *Comment by Simon Lieschke* which gives nil information about what topic the comment is on.

Could this be changed to include the question title like *Comment by Simon Lieschke on Documentation on the SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS environment variable*? This would help tremendously for giving some context as to what the comment is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good idea; implemented!